# How to make an instanceOf check testable

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't allow string type hinting.  I want to check the below item and throw an error if it's not an instance of a certain class.  Is it possible to unit test this, whether by mocking or performing this check some other way?

```
    if (!is_array($schedules)) {
        $schedules = array($schedules);
    }
    foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
        if (($schedule instanceOf Schedulable) === false) {
            throw new ScheduleException('Schedule for "'.$command->getName().'" is not an instance of Schedulable');
        }

        //more stuff here
    }
```

The trouble I'm running into is that `$schedule` is a mock. and I need to test what happens in the `//more stuff here` section.

Currently, `$schedule` is an instance of `Mockery::mock('Schedule');`.

Comment: Just catch exception in a test case (or `@expectedException` which is basically the same)?

Comment: @zerkms I realize now that I didn't include everything I needed to.

Comment: The issue isn't clear yet though. So, `$schedule` is a mock. Okay, so?

Comment: Yes, its a mock that needs to pass a check to see if its an instance

Comment: and the problem is... ?

Comment: The problem is that I need the `instanceOf` check to not throw an exception when I pass a mock.

Comment: it should pass the check. How did you create a mock?

Comment: @zerkms I updated the post to include how it's created.

Comment: `Schedule` != `Schedulable`

Comment: Right... `Schedulable` is a class.  I'm mocking a class that extends it.

Comment: `var_dump(class_exists('Schedule', false), is_subclass_of('Schedule', 'Schedulable'));` ? Must be both `true`

Comment: @zerkms 
bool(false)
bool(false)

Comment: so, `Schedule` class isn't declared (or autoloaded). So Mockery creates a class that inherits *something*, but not what you expect. Is `Schedule` a fully qualified name? Do you have any autoloading?

Comment: @zerkms - Sorry, I had left out the namespaces so as to not reveal the application I'm working on.  Here's the correct output: bool(true)
bool(false)

Comment: it means that `Schedule` doesn't implement the `Schedulable` interface (assuming both class name and interface name are specified correctly)

Comment: You're right... I had moved the namespace of a class that was being mocked and didn't come back and update this mocked class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have discussed in the comments one should ensure that:

1. The class is already defined or can be autoloaded
2. The fully qualified name should be used